# Insert a Row into Excel but keep its current formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `Sum` on specific Cells (lets say `"A1:A5"`) in my Excel worksheet. Usually, whenever I insert a row manually on `"A1"`, The sum is expanded, so the new Range is `"A1:A6"`. Now when I insert a row using VBA at `"A1"`, my sum goes from `"A2:A6"`, not `"A1:A6"`. How can I insert a row but basically keep the current formatting (so that the sum is automatically expanded)?

My code I use for inserting:

```
 dest.Rows(index).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
 dest.Rows(index).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

where `dest` is the worksheet I want to expand.

Edit:

I tried to use a macro and use that code, that did sadly not work.

The generated code:

```
Rows("167:167").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

My new code:

```
 dest.Rows(index).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 dest.Rows(index).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

That did not change the outcome.

Edit2:

I am going to provide a picture to clarify what I want to do:

[image: What it looks like]

Whenever I manually add a line (`rightclick line 152 -> insert cells`) this little table is expanded and everything is shifted down, so lets assume:

I have a `SUM` in cell `B,180` that goes from B:50 to B:179, now the `SUM` is in cell `B,181` and goes from `B:50` to `B:180`. Also, the formatting of the table is used for the new line (as far as the table goes, so columns `A:K` are having the background/borders of the cells above.

When I use my code for that, it is just a new blank line inserted without keeping the formatting.

Comment: The easiest way to solve formatting issues in Excel is to record a macro and see what it produces when you do the correct movements. Usually the solution is quite ok after some optimizations.

Comment: @Vityata That did not work for me sadly, I edited my post

Comment: *Usually, why I insert a row manually on "A1", The sum is expanded, so the new Range is "A1:A6"* - does it really happen? Or it happens only when you insert a row on `A2`, not on `A1`?

Comment: @Vityata I updated my problem description, please see the pictures. Indeed he might expand when I pick A2, but in this case he should expand in any case I guess, the problem turns out to be that he does not keep the formatting, even with `CopyOrigin` provided as an argument

Comment: To avoid this situation, I always keep at least two rows available, so I can insert new rows between them. Then the Insert method always copies all cell formatting, including borders, colors, and number formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this worked:

```
Sub copyExpanded()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A5")

    rng.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    rng.EntireRow.Copy rng.Offset(1).EntireRow

End Sub
```